# Adjust vertical alignment in footline of beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, vertical-alignment

Using the beamer class: When I put the page number in the footline next to a navigation icon they align on the bottom of their bounding box. Unfortunately the navigation bounding box is bigger than my text so they end up at different heights. But I would like to align them center in order to get them on the same height. I tried to shift the sheet numbers up a bit in various ways I could think of, but I failed.

(Allmost)-minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}        %disable standard navigation
\setbeamercolor{footlinecolor}{fg=white,bg=black}   %set color of footline
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=gray}  %redefine color of dimmed aspects of navigation bar
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red}     %this is ignored somehow


%define custom footline
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=1.6cm,wd=\paperwidth]{footlinecolor}
    \vspace{1.1cm}
    \hfill
    \fbox{
        \insertframenavigationsymbol 
        \insertsectionnavigationsymbol
    }
    \fbox{
        \tiny{\insertframenumber{} of \inserttotalframenumber}
    }
   \end{beamercolorbox}
}


\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Introduction}
    Lorum Ipsum
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah just found the answer: 
Put both elements in their own minipage and give them the [c] option:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=1.6cm,wd=\paperwidth]{footlinecolor}
    \vspace{1.1cm}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[c]{2cm}
        \insertframenavigationsymbol 
        \insertsectionnavigationsymbol
    \end{minipage}      
    \begin{minipage}[c]{2cm}
        \tiny{\insertframenumber{} of \inserttotalframenumber}
    \end{minipage}      
   \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```